# Selecting multiple odd or even columns/rows for dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, pca

Is there a way in R to select many non-consecutive i.e. odd or even rows/columns?

I'm plotting the loadings for my Principal Components Analysis.  I have 84 rows of data ordered like this: `x_1` `y_1` `x_2`..... `x_42`   `y_42`

And at the moment I am creating the dataframes for the x and y loadings figures like this:

```
data.pc = princomp(as.matrix(data))

x.loadings <- data.frame(x=data.pc$loadings[c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 ,15, 17, 19, 
21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41), 1])

yloadings <- data.frame(y=data.pc$loadings[c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 
22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42), 1])
```

Surely there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `?seq`

Comment: Note that you're talking about selecting columns, but your code selects rows from column 1.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can always generate sequences with seq:

```
even_indexes<-seq(2,42,2)
odd_indexes<-seq(1,41,2)
```

Then,

```
  x.loadings <- data.frame(x=data.pc$loadings[odd_indexes,1])
```

Comment: I don't understand why the accepted answer to a question about SELECTING odd/even rows or columns is about GENERATING odd or even numbers.

Answer (score 87):

When logical vectors are used for indexing, they are recycled so this gets you odd columns or odd rows

```
 calld[ c(TRUE,FALSE), ]  # rows
 calld[ , c(TRUE,FALSE) ] #columns
```

Even rows or columns:

```
 calld[ !c(TRUE,FALSE), ]  # rows
 calld[ , !c(TRUE,FALSE) ] #columns
```

Every third column:

```
  calld[ , c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE) ]   #columns 1,4,7 , ....
```

A recent commenter claims this no longer works. I'm not finding that in R 4.0.4 running in Ubuntu:

```
> d <- data.frame(as.list(1:10))  # simple example construction
> d
  X1L X2L X3L X4L X5L X6L X7L X8L X9L X10L
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
> d[, c(TRUE,FALSE)]
  X1L X3L X5L X7L X9L
1   1   3   5   7   9
> d[, c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)]  # example: # of columns not exact multiple of length of logical vector
  X1L X4L X7L X10L
1   1   4   7   10
```

Comment: Beste answer. If N becomes big in "every Nth column/row" then `c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,7)` (with 7 being N-1) may be used as readable and concise alternative.

Comment: Could you explain the above code? calld[ !c(TRUE,FALSE), ]

Comment: @Standin.Wolf : Not sure what part is confusing you. The "!" basically inverts the logical vector so that it really means: `calld[ c(FALSE,TRUE) , ]`

Comment: in `R 4.0.0` very unfortunately, the syntax ` calld[ , !c(TRUE,FALSE) ]` doesn't work any more. You must specify exactly the correct number of columns or rows to repeat.

Comment: @AgileBean: I just tested it again on a simple 10 column dataframe and it seems to work for me. You need to post a counter example if you are still seeing evidence of failure to adhere to R's admittedly unusual feature of extending vectors by implicit repetition(AKA "recycling").

Answer (score 41):

I wish to add the `tidyverse` style approach to this problem, using the `%%` operator.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(V1 = seq(26), V2 = letters)

df %>% filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) ## Select even rows
df %>% filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) ## Select odd rows
df %>% filter(row_number() %% 3 == 1) ## Select every 3rd row starting from first row
```

You can use the same idea to *delete* every n-th row, of course. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942519/deleting-every-n-th-row-in-a-dataframe).

Answer (score 7):

Use `%%` in combination with `seq_len` to create vector for indexing your data frame to find even and odds columns/rows

Try something like this:

```
even <- seq_len(ncol(data.pc)) %% 2   # index
x.loadings <- data.frame(x=data.pc$loadings[even, ])
y.loadings <- data.frame(x=data.pc$loadings[!even, ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is data.table approach

1. Make a simple data.table with columns (10) and rows (100)

`df = data.table(sapply(1:10, rnorm, n=100))`

2. Get the even/odd rows:

Even
`df[df[, .I%%2==0]]` or `df[seq(2,.N,2)]`

Odd
`df[df[, .I%%2==1]]` or `df[seq(1,.N,2)]`

3. Get the even/odd columns

Even
`df[,.SD, .SDcols=seq(2,ncol(df),2)]`

Odd
`df[,.SD, .SDcols=seq(1,ncol(df),2)]`

Comment: Can you actually use `.SD` inside the brackets?

Comment: hmm, not sure.. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: @MaliRemorker I added the use of .SD for selecting odd/even columns - thanks!