# How does this odds/even extraction work in R language?

Tags: r, algorithm

```
> a <- sample(c(1:10), 20, replace = TRUE)
> a
 [1]  6  3  6  2  6  9  3  9  9  8  2 10  7  9  1  5  3 10  5  5
> a[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
 [1] 6 6 6 3 9 2 7 1 3 5
```

Why a[c(TRUE,FALSE)] gives me an ODD elements of my array? c(TRUE, FALSE) has length of 2. And on my mind, this supposed to give me a single index 1, which is TRUE.

Why is this comes by this way?

Comment: The vector `c(TRUE,FALSE)` is recycled to the length of a, thus becoming a vetor of alternating TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24440258/680068

Comment: To illustrate, try: `cbind.data.frame(x = 1:10, odd = c(TRUE, FALSE), even = c(FALSE, TRUE))`

Comment: ok, @zx8754, your explanation has clarified my issue pretty good. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical subsets are recycled to match the length of the vector (numerical subsets are not recycled).

From `help("[")`:

> Arguments
>
> **i, j, …**
>
> ...
>
> For `[`-indexing only: `i`, `j`, `…` can be logical vectors,
> indicating elements/slices to select. Such vectors are recycled if
> necessary to match the corresponding extent. `i`, `j`, `…` can also be
> negative integers, indicating elements/slices to leave out of the
> selection.
>
> When indexing arrays by `[` a single argument `i` can be a matrix with
> as many columns as there are dimensions of `x`; the result is then a
> vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row
> of `i`.

---

To illustrate, try:

```
cbind.data.frame(x = 1:10, odd = c(TRUE, FALSE), even = c(FALSE, TRUE))
#     x   odd  even
# 1   1  TRUE FALSE
# 2   2 FALSE  TRUE
# 3   3  TRUE FALSE
# 4   4 FALSE  TRUE
# 5   5  TRUE FALSE
# 6   6 FALSE  TRUE
# 7   7  TRUE FALSE
# 8   8 FALSE  TRUE
# 9   9  TRUE FALSE
# 10 10 FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`a[TRUE]` gives your all the elements and `a[FALSE]` gives none. for `a[c(TRUE,FALSE]` it will wrap `length(c(TRUE,FALSE))` which is 2 to `length(a)` which is 20, so for example it would be like `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, ....` , then it will give you just `odds` indexes.