# How to select rows based on pre-determined gaps (R)?

Tags: r

I recently post another question asking how I could create a new data.frame based on a colunm variable. I thought it would fix my problem but I realize now that I was asking the wrong thing.
What I mean with my question is, how I can select rows in a constant gap and create a new data.frame with them?
Like, if I have:

```
1   A   B   C
2   D   E   F
3   G   H   I
4   J   K   L
5   M   N   O
6   P   Q   R
```

I will want to select the rows that grow in two to two like:

```
2  D   E   F
4  J   K   L
6  P   Q   R
```

But actually in my case, I need to select the rows that are groing in 40 to 40 and create a new data.frame with them.

Sorry for another post, but I will be really glad if you guys could help me. I'm a new user of R.

Comment: what do you mean by growing in 40 to 40?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select rows 40,80,120,160.... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy with the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% dplyr::filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0)
```

Basically, you are calling the row number and selecting only the even ones. If you wanted to go for every 40 rows, you would be doing `row_number() %% 40 == 0`. If you wanted to start from another row and get every 40 rows, you just need to change the `0` to another number, as the `%%` operator performs modular divsion.

Comment: Thank you! It's very easy indeed... I was almost given up and selecting the rows by hand haha =)

Comment: I think it is entirely possible that you just missed the right search keywords---if you had searched for "every nth row r dataframe", you would have gotten [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440258/selecting-multiple-odd-or-even-columns-rows-for-dataframe) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942519/deleting-every-n-th-row-in-a-dataframe). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use R base functions if you don't want to load any extra packages:

Option 1

```
df[seq_len(nrow(df))%%2==0,]
```

Option 2

```
subset(df, seq_len(nrow(df))%%2==0)
```