# Reshaping columns of the same dataframe into one

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a `df` looking like this:

```
Department   ID   Category   Category.ID
    NA       NA      NA          NA
   Sales     101     2           4
   Sales     101     2           4
    NA       NA      NA          NA
   Sales     101     2           4
   Sales     101     2           4
    NA       NA      NA          NA
   Sales     101     2           4
   Sales     101     2           4

df = data.frame(Department = rep(c(NA, 'Sales', 'Sales'), times = 3),
                ID = rep(c(NA, 101, 101), times = 3),
                Category.Department = rep(c(NA, 2, 2), times = 3),
                Category.ID = rep(c(NA, 4, 4), times = 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I would like to have an output like this, where in only one column I can have the `Department` and `ID` and in another one, the `Category`. The `NA` in each column it is important to separate the groups.

```
New.Col   Category
  NA         NA
 Sales       2
  101        4
  NA         NA
 Sales       2
  101        4
  NA         NA
 Sales       2
  101        4
```

So far I tried with `transpose`, `sapply` and a `function` but it has not worked as I expected. Any suggestions in `base`?

Comment: is the output just an example? I can not see the logic behind that in the `merge` context. It looks like a formatting from wide to long format.

Comment: Why do you need to have the `NA` row? Is it necessary?

Comment: The `NA` is necessary to separate each group. I also just tried with `reshape` but it is not giving the output I need.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. The logic behind your expected output is not clear. What are you trying to do here? Please provide some details/explanations. Why the particular order of rows in your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't accept an accept without true expected output.

```
df$group <- rep(1:3, times = 3)

df2 <- reshape(df[df$group != 3,], direction = "long", varying = list(New.col = c(1,2), Category = c(3,4)),
               idvar = "id", v.names = c("New.col", "Category"))

df3 <- df2[order(df2$id),]

df3[!(df3$time == 1 & df3$group == 1), c(3,4)] 

    New.col Category
1.2    <NA>       NA
2.1   Sales        2
2.2     101        4
3.2    <NA>       NA
4.1   Sales        2
4.2     101        4
5.2    <NA>       NA
6.1   Sales        2
6.2     101        4
```

Comment: It works good... now I just need to find a way to delete the remaining data duplicates :-P Thanks!!

Comment: Which ones do you consider duplicates?

Comment: On your example, rows `3.1`, `3.2`, `6.1`, `6.2`, `9.1` & `9.2` since I just need the data once per group and not twice.

Comment: So, following your solutions, plus [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942519/deleting-every-n-th-row-in-a-dataframe) I got the desired output... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach than casting to long format, which relies in `coalesce`. In addition, I created a group variable and removed the `NA` rows as they will not serve a purpose in your analysis, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.))) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(contains('ID')), funs(lag)) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(contains('Department')), funs(lead)) %>% 
 mutate(new.col = coalesce(Department, as.character(ID)), 
        category = coalesce(Category.Department, Category.ID)) %>% 
 select(grp, new.col, category) %>% 
 distinct()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
> # Groups:   grp [3]
>     grp new.col category
>   <int> <chr>      <dbl>
> 1     1 Sales          2
> 2     1 101            4
> 3     2 Sales          2
> 4     2 101            4
> 5     3 Sales          2
> 6     3 101            4
> ```