# Deleting every nth column from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to reduce the size of a dataframe by removing every third column.

Here is my example dataframe:

```
example = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y=c(1,2,3,4), z=c(1,2,3,4), w=c(1,2,3,4), p=c(1,2,3,4), q=c(1,2,3,4), r=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Which looks like this

```
x y z w p q r
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

I would like to convert it into something that looks like this

```
x y w p r
1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4
```

I have been able to reduce the number of rows using tidyverse:

```
example <- example %>% dplyr::filter(row_number() %% 3 != 1)
```

But I can't figure out how to delete every third column.

I have also tried to use this line:

```
example[, !(c%%3==0)]
```

from [Deleting every n-th row in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942519/deleting-every-n-th-row-in-a-dataframe) but I keep getting this error: 
Error in c%%3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in a very simple way in base.

```r
example[, c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
```

The logical vector will repeat as needed for the columns. If you want it to scale, you can do something like this.

```r
n <- 3
example[, c(rep(TRUE, n - 1), FALSE)]
```

---

If you prefer, the `dplyr` equivalent of this can be:

```r
example %>%
  select(everything()[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
library(dplyr)

col_index <- seq(1:ncol(example)) 
example %>% select(col_index[col_index %% 3 != 0])
```